# Creating a (candidate) template file

Tags: theming

Drupal: 7.x
Theme: Bartik

I am using the newly created Commune module to display wall posts on a user's profile page (panels.) Each post has a form below it for comments. The comment form is created by the commune module.

I am trying to theme that comment form but I can't find a candidate template file using Themer Devel. The closest template file is commune.tpl.php (in the core module/commune directory) but this includes a bunch of stuff I don't want to include in the theming.

How do I go about finding a candidate template file or creating one I can use to theme the comment form?

Thanks. :)

Comment: it probably uses the core comment.tpl.php, which should be in the templates folder of the Bartik theme

Answer (score 1):

The default way to find theme template names as of Drupal 7.33 is to enable theme_debug in your settings.php file. If the template name is available then you should see it in the rendered markup of the page by using your browsers inspect element feature. You can read more about how to find template names here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656

As for the certain template name you are looking for, there may or may not be one depending on what the developer used to create the markup. Sometimes the markup is made in a different way for performance reasons. You will probably have to inspect the module code to get the answer there. If I have time over the weekend I may dive into that but hopefully you can find it with the theme_debug feature.

Comment: I enabled theme_debug but still could not find an available template. I didn't know about theme_debug and it looks like it is a great tool for theming. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: I have done more investigating on this and I thought it was better to rephrase the question. It is posted here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164646/naming-a-template-file